# How to selectively forbid deleting of tasks in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: properties

I am new to SharePoint, sorry if answer to my question is obvious.

I want to forbid deleting some tasks for users. 
I can use event receiver for my purpose:

```
public override void ItemDeleting(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{  
    if (...) 
    {
        properties.ErrorMessage = "The task can not be deleted";
        properties.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

But I can't pass data for checking if I can delete the task. 
I've tryed to use

```
properties.ListItem.Properties["ForbidDeleting"].ToString().Equals("true")
```

in the receiver's condition but is there any posibility to set such property in the CreateTask invoking method? I've tryed using Extended properties for it, but this approach  doesn't work.

```
 ....
 task.ExtendedProperties["ForbidDeleting"] = "true"
```

I can create my class for keeping task Guids and it ForbidDeleting property, but I think it is not a solution but workaround.

Could you help me please? How can I set some task properties (in the CreateTask invoking method) and get it in the event receiver. Is there any built in way to do it?

Thank you in advance.

PS: Sorry for my writing. English is not my native language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you retrieve Extended Properties? I used this code in my castom form in the past. I think it should work in event receiver.

```
Hashtable extendedProperties = SPWorkflowTask.GetExtendedPropertiesAsHashtable(taskItem);
var value = extendedProperties[key].ToString();
```

Comment: Yes. It's really works!